# How to properly close the UISearchBar dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

What is the proper way to dynamically (from code) to close the UISearchbar and to display it in its default state? (This is not a duplicate)

By default state, meaning it meets the following criteria:

- Removes the cursor from the search bar
- Removes the cancel button
- Searchbar loses focus
- There is no transparent grey backdrop/background
- The end result should look the same before the searchbar was clicked

I have tried the following, however the grey background overlay tint still remains.

```
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.endEditing(true)
        searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .none
```

Even setting isActive to false does not close the searchbar and remove focus:

```
 func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
     print("searchBarShouldBeginEditing called")
     searchController.isActive = false
     return true
 }
```

On android, to achieve all this, we would just have to call one method:

```
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this with Swift?

Answer (score 0):

When your closing the UISearchbar then please add

```
searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor =  UIColor.clear
```

So the code will look like:

```
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
   searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.endEditing(true)
   searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
   searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .none
   searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor =  UIColor.clear
```

May it helps you.